# How to verify if argument is in created list in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I have written below code in robot framework. How to verify if that ${args} is in ${Mylist}

```
Create Article
    [Arguments]  ${args}
    ${MyList}=    Create List    'Federal News'   'EY News'
    Run Keyword If   ${args}  in  ${MyList}   Run keywords  Click Element  ${tab1_Xpath}   AND  Wait Until Page Contains  Federal News
```

And I am calling `Create Article ${arg}` from another file. If I use the above script I am getting the error.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Is the data that you're passing in including the quote marks? In other words, is `${args}` something like `Federal News` or `'Federal News'`?

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to Run keyword if must be a valid expression. Because you have more than one space around "in", robot thinks `${args}` is the expression, and `in` and `${MyList}` are additional arguments. TO fix this you need to have a single space on either side of "in".

The second problem is that you're creating a list of strings that includes quote marks. I'm guessing that you don't actually want that. If you want your list to contain the string `Federal News` you need to omit the quotes.

Finally, the expression needs to be valid python syntax after variable substitution. Since you're comparing strings, you need to either quote the arguments or use the special variable syntax `$args`. Using the special syntax is usually the best solution, since you don't h ave to worry about whether the variable itself contains quotes.

Finally, I would recommend using `${arg}` rather than `${args}` since it's a scalar rather than a list.

Assuming your data does not actually include the quote marks, here's how I would do it:

```
Create article
    [Arguments]  ${arg}
    ${MyList}=    Create List    Federal News   EY News
    Run Keyword If   $arg in $MyList   Run keywords  
    ...  Click Element  ${tab1_Xpath}   
    ...  AND  Wait Until Page Contains  Federal News
```

With that, you can run the keyword like this:

```
Create article  Federal News
```

Comment: Thank you so much Bryan. It's working liking a charm

Answer (score 0):

Bryan has the perfect answer, here is a workaround to do the same task by using below keywords from collections library

1)Run Keyword And Return Status - Returns True or False for a keyword success or failure

2)List Should Contain Value - Check items in list

```
Create article
    [Arguments]  ${arg}
    ${MyList}=    Create List    Federal News   EY News

    ${status}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    List Should Contain Value    ${mylist}    ${arg}
    Run Keyword If   ${status}==True   Run keywords  
    ...  Click Element  ${tab1_Xpath}   
    ...  AND  Wait Until Page Contains  Federal News
```